# jQuery having problems passing variables to a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using `$.post()` with jQuery in order to pass a few variables over to a form. The first form is for information input, and the page that it posts to is a "preview" page, containing that information in a proper setting. I use `$_REQUEST` for getting the variables, but it doesn't seem to work. When the page redirects, there are no variables filled out.

Here's the jQuery I use:

```
$('#createEnter').live('click',function() {
        if($("#createForm").valid())
        {
            $.post('coupPreview.php', $('#createForm').serialize(), function(){
                window.location.replace("../coupPreview");
            });
        }
    });
```

Then I post to coupPreview.php, and redirect to there, so I theoretically should see all of the variables, but I always see nothing, as if no variables were passed. I had this as a pure PHP/HTML post previously and it worked fine, so all of the other code should be correct.

Any help?

Comment: try to output variables from the `coupPreview.php` without redirecting on your firebug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually making 2 separate requests, in one you are doing an ajax post with the form info.. which, the result of probably has the data filled out, but then you are redirecting the browser to the page and not sending any information with the request so there is no data to show.

Have you considered instead just changing your post and redirect to have your form action be the page you want to go to and post the values as you navigate?

Something to the effect of:

```
<form action="coupPreview.php" method="post">
    <!-- Your Inputs Here -->
    <input type="submit" onclick="return $('#createForm').valid()" />
</form>
```

Of course I don't know what your goal was with the ajax call so this might not be at all what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try echoing the $_REQUEST value during $.post and then alerting it before you redirect to ensure that it has worked:

```
$('#createEnter').live('click',function() {
    if($("#createForm").valid())
    {
        $.post('coupPreview.php', $('#createForm').serialize(), function(data){
            alert(data);

            window.location.replace("../coupPreview");
        });
    }
});
```

Additionally you might try:

```
var data = $('#createForm').serialize();

$.post('coupPreview.php', data, function(data){...
```

And then use Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to confirm that the values in "data" is correct.